# Delphi set ComboEdit Item from a String?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm currently displaying "merchandise" in a ListView, the listview has article, quantity, iemsls and name.

On DoubleClick of the item I want to read the variables and put them in TEdit field, and 'iemsls' in a ComboEdit which has items pre-written, how can I check which item from the ComboEdit equals the same as of the String and set it to that?

```
      igiDoubleTap:
     begin
     global_norakstisanadoc_editing := true;
     SelectedItemIndex := F_SS_MAIN.ListView2.Selected.index;

     ListView2.Enabled := false;
     SpeedButton6.Enabled := false;
     SpeedButton7.Enabled := false;

     quant_bef := (TListItemText(F_SS_MAIN.ListView1.Items.AppearanceItem[index].Objects.FindDrawable('Text2')).Text);
     quant_aft := StringReplace(quant_bef, 'gb', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

     Edit_artikuls_norakstisana.Text := ListView2.Items.Item[SelectedItemIndex].View.FindObject('artikuls').Data.ToString;
     edit_daudzums_norakstisana.Text := quant_aft;
     label_prece_from_ean.Text := ListView2.Items.Item[SelectedItemIndex].View.FindObject('prece').Data.ToString;

     ComboEdit := ListView2.Items.Item[SelectedItemIndex].View.FindObject('iemsls').Data.ToString;

     end;
```

This is currently the DoubleTap method I'm using

Comment: 1. Read the string which you want to search for. 2. Iterate over each item in the combo. 3. Compare the search string against each item in the combo yielded by step 2.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is there a way of exiting a for loop? I'm currently going into a loop from 0 to ComboEdit1.items.count, and doing an if ComboEdit1.items[ComboEdit1.ItemIndex[i]] = 'the string', how can i exit the loop when the string is found?

Comment: Read the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Control_Loops

Comment: Take a look at 1. the Delphi Language Guide. Read if from begin(ning) to end. 2. Then concentrate on the command Break.

Comment: a `for` loop is an unconditional loop, it will run until it reached the ends of its index. If you want your loop to stop on a condition, use a conditional loop, such as `while do` or `repeat until` There are ways to break from a `for `loop, but IMO you  have used the wrong loop when you need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both VCL and FMX, The `TComboBox.Items` property is a `TStrings` object that has an `IndexOf()` method, and `TComboBox` has an `ItemIndex` property for setting the currently selected item by index.

So, try this:

```
ComboEdit1.ItemIndex := ComboEdit1.Items.IndexOf(
  ListView2.Items.Item[SelectedItemIndex].View.FindObject('iemsls').Data.ToString
);
```